# Transforming XML using XSL fails

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform my XML using XSL. However, I am facing an issue here. Help required.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

My XSL file:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

I am getting the following error:

```
XPath evaluation returned no result.
```

Thanks

Comment: Your "XML file" is anything but not an XML file. The same goes for the XSLT. Please post code samples that would at least not cause syntax errors.

Comment: You need to show enough detail so other people can reproduce your error, otherwise we can't tell what caused it. For example, it could be the problem that someone reports nearly every day, that the stylesheet ignores the namespace of the source document; but it could be 1000 other things as well, I just mention that one because it's the most popular blunder.